# POST request from JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using latest version of JMeter and trying to make a POST request from JMeter however I am not able to see dropdown to change HTTP method . can you please suggest why dropdown is not visible to me ?

Please find below screen shot of JMeter . It has no dropdown to specify HTTP method.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking into HTTP Request Defaults **configuration element** where all the default values can be specified. It is good that you have it as if you will need to change URL, protocol, path, whatever you will be able to do it in one place instead of visiting each and every HTTP Request Sampler. See [Why It's SO Important To Use JMeter's HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)

However it is **not a sampler** so it won't do any work, you need to add [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to your test plan, there you will be able to set request method, etc.

Answer (score 0):

implementation in HTTP Request Defaults moved to Advanced tab

Click Advanced and choose between HTTPClient4 and Java