# Apache Jmeter version 3.2 r1790748- Implementation option is missing in HTTP Request, could anyone point out why it is so?

Tags: jmeter

Apache Jmeter version 3.2 r1790748- Implementation option is missing in HTTP Request, could anyone point out how to enable this option.

I'm trying to follow a video tutorial with regards to post method using jmeter and I got below error..

Only option I didnt selected is implementation-java, which I can find in my jmeter version.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:654)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:413)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST request from JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081038/post-request-from-jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from JMeter 3.2 you can find "Implementation" drop-down on the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image: JMeter Implementation Advanced HTTP]

I would recommend amending it using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults) as this way you will not only be able to set a setting for all HTTP Request samplers in scope, but going forward if you change your mind you will need to change implementation back to HTTPClient4 in one place only.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, couldnt believe i missed that even though i looked at the advanced tab.